# MEMS microphone encode to AAC low performance

Tags: microprocessor, sound, ultrasound, encoding, mems-microphone

I am looking for a solution to encode the data from a MEMS microphone to AAC LC. I have a small microcontroller that is very low power but that lacks the RAM required for encoding so I am looking for simplest possible solution.

Are there any MEMS microphone that can natively provide a AAC stream?

Or are there any chip that can do this with low price (preferably <$2, volume 1000), low number of pins and small footprint?

Any ideas o. How to solve the problem would be appreciated.

I also wonder how I can normalize the volume level of the microphone. Is this done natively by digital MEMS microphoned?

EDIT:
Would adding a PSRAM over SPI etc solve the problem or would I need to rewrite the entire AAC lib to make this work? It is not possible to memory map additional RAM in the chip I use.

Answer (score 7):

> I have a small microcontroller that is very low power but that lacks the RAM required for encoding so I am looking for simplest possible solution.

Get a better microcontroller; that's really all.

> Are there any MEMS microphone that can natively provide a AAC stream?

No.

> Or are there any chip that can do this with low price, low number of pins and small footprint?

Microcontrollers :) Note that I'm not saying you need to replace your ultra-low-power microcontroller! But the external ASIC you're looking for is really just a computer powerful enough to run the codec you want – and that might well mean that when needed, you power a second microcontroller.

Let me do a bit of quick estimates in my head: from my DRM / DAB+ days, I remember that the `fdk-aac` AAC-LC works on 40 ms chunks of 16bit samples at 8 kS/s (assuming you're aiming for speech). So, that's 640 B of samples you need to hold per chunk.

Then, we need to do a MDCT, so I'll throw in another 4 kB of RAM for that (we'll hold coefficients in RAM, probably), apply a psychoacoustic model and quantize, another 8 kB, then need to do the entropy coding, 8 kB more.

So, in total, we're talking 32 kB to 64 kB of RAM necessary. Falls nicely into the midrange Cortex-M range!

> I also wonder how I can normalize the volume level of the microphone. Is this done natively by digital MEMS microphoned?

Some microphones have adaptive gain control. You'll find out in the datasheet.

Comment: Presumably a Cortex-M can also run better codecs like Opus, so a firmware upgrade could let you switch over in future.  (some random opinions I found on Reddit are that an M7 definitely can, and probably an M4: https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/5dz8kg/encoding_opus_on_cortex_m4_or_low_power_dsp/)

Comment: @PeterCordes you probably wouldn't want to implement all of OPUS on an M4, but only the application specific part relevant to your use case, but yeah. But I think if OP is asking for specifically AAC-LC, then there's probably compatibility involved

Comment: Yeah, I assumed they had a reason for AAC, presumably compatibility with something, that's why I said "in future", not "they should do that instead now".

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The microcontroller I use is an Arm Cortex M33. I think it is powerful enough to do this, but the problem is I only have a couple of kB left of RAM.
I had the idea to add like an PSRAM over SPI or similar, but the device lacks the functionality to memory map the additional RAM, so I dont know if I could get AAC to work with that without making too much changes...

Comment: @PeterCordes I actually tried cross compiling Opus for the chip I use, but same issue there, too little RAM. Opus could actually be a solution, but it would be better to run AAC-LC for compatibility reasons. If I run Opus I might need to transcode it in a later process.

Comment: @www.jensolsson.se: If you're archiving your data, transcode on the fly to high-bitrate AAC from Opus should be basically transparent if necessary at all, and give you the compression efficiency of Opus for your archives.  I'd hope that as time passes, *more* stuff will be compatible with Opus.  But IDK what your use-case is, I just know that the open-source implementation of Opus is world-class, vs. there being multiple not-great AAC encoder libraries, and the most efficient ones being binary-only or at least encumbered somehow so often not built in to distro packages of FFmpeg.

Comment: @www.jensolsson.se yeah, while fdk-aac in all its fixed-point glory is certainly meant to run on devices such as yours, I don't think you specifically want to put the memory for codec purposes into external, non-mapped RAM. Your application sounds really interesting! My guess is that you could do something like taking the memory that is used by some task that is *not* run while the codec runs, put it on external memory, and fetch it back afterwards; paging (not to disk as your PC when it swaps, but to external memory)! That of course comes with interesting constraints, like you needing to

Comment: define a "swappable" memory arena in your linker script, manually using the memory from there, adding hooks to page out / page in the memory of the current task on task switch and so on. Then there's the cost/effort tradeoff: if you need to buy an extra component anyway (the external RAM), including development costs, are you really saving if you're not just adding a cheap-as-possible microcontroller for the codec alone? Note that the microcontroller, aside from maybe two DMA-capable serial communication peripherals, really needs no special peripherals – potentially that allows for cheap MCUs?

Comment: @PeterCordes re: encumbered implementations: yeah, that used to be terrible about fdk-aac, but the encumberment was mostly that you still needed to buy a license to *sell devices* doing AAC; with these patents lapsed, that restriction has become meaningless.

Answer (score 4):

> with low price

One of the [STM32 family](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus.html) will almost certainly see you right. They go from about $2 up to, well, a lot more! What you call "low price" is going to be specific to your application though - it'll be different depending on if it's high-end scientific equipment, cheap consumer electronics, or disposable greetings cards with a recorded message.

Level adjustment in software is the way to go - it doesn't need extra components and it's well within the capabilities of most devices. If it's going to be automatic then you could best do this this too with a soft-knee compressor, make-up gain, and a limiter at the end. The problem though is that you need to start with enough ADC resolution for the application. If it's a greeting card recording, 16-bit is more than enough, and you might even get away with a 12-bit ADC. That'll reduce to 8-bit or less after level adjustment, but you don't really need super quality for that application. If it's a serious recording though, you want at least 16-bit resolution after level adjustment, so 24-bit ADCs are the standard for audio recording equipment.

Comment: AAC doesn't do lossless, so we can probably rule out "high-end scientific equipment" in this specific case.  But yeah, there's still a range from one-off to mass-market.

Comment: I realize that low cost was a bit vague, I will update my question. My main microcontroller is around $5 and adding audio is a small additional feature so it need to be in line with this.